# Обнуление this внутри класса

Tags: c++

Как сделать вот так? И чтобы оно заработало.

```
class A{
public:
    A *_n;

    void n(){
        if(!this) return ;
        *this=*_n;
    }
};

A z; z._n=0;
z.n();
```

Проблема в *this=*_n; программа падает, если _n=0. Есть ли возможность сделать this==0 изнутри класса?
Захотелось полениться и не писать a=a->_n; сократив до a.n(); И главное оно ж работает, пока _n!=0;

Comment: Чего вы пытаетесь добиться? Как вообще можно сократить "`a=a->_n`" до "`a.n()`"? Вы написали код, который делает dereference для null pointer, что [по стандарту является undefined behavior'ом](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6793262/why-dereferencing-a-null-pointer-is-undefined-behaviour), поэтому у вас, естественно, все "падает".

Comment: По стандарту, `this` является const и никогда не может быть равным `nullptr`. Проверка

    if (!this)

бессмысленна.

Comment: много ли вообще было бы смысла в this, не будь он константным?

Comment: Я пытался поэкспериментировать. Я отбросил этот вариант из-за того, что он ломал структуру указателей.

Да ладно if(!this) отличная штука. Вот например тут A *m=a.Get(thisuser)->Get("locations")->Get(location). Мне не нужно проверять, а не вернет ли Get() ноль. Убирается куча лишних проверок.

Comment: Можно наверное покапать в сторону макросов. Либо сделать враппер шаблонный который будет возвращать нул на попытку вызвать метод у нула :-) Но вообще, Вы наверное ошиблись инструментом, если хотите так лениться :-)

Comment: @mikelsv: Поймите, что по стандарту код, разыменовывающий нулевой указатель, является UB. Он имеет право крешнуться, имеет право отформатировать ваш винчестер и настучать на вас в компетентные органы. То, что MSVC с выключенной оптимизацией пропускает такой код — случайная деталь. Хороший оптимизатор имеет право **выкинуть** проверку `if (!this)`, потому что по стандарту, повторю ещё раз, `this` никогда не бывает равен `nullptr`, а разыменование `nullptr` — undefined behaviour.

«Оно у меня работает» — негодная отмазка.

Comment: `this` **[ни при каких обстоятельствах не может быть равен NULL](https://www.viva64.com/ru/b/0226/)**, даже оптимизации компилятора под это заточены.

Answer (score 2):

this - это константный указатель, из него можно получить только адрес текущего объекта и больше ничего. то есть вы не сможете изменить его никаким способом.

Comment: ТС не пытается изменить `this`. Он пытается изменить `*this`, то есть вызвать `A::operator=()`.